# Как очищать БД, что бы, при повторном запуске приложения на эмуляторе, она была пустая?

Tags: java, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Моё приложение считывает данные из EditText, записывает в БД(SQLite), и выводит всю БД. Но при перезапуске приложения на Эмуляторе, в БД уже присутствуют те записи, которые я добавлял.

Так вот, как мне перезапускать приложение, что бы оно было с чистой БД? И возможно ли, что именно из-за этого, приложение не запускается на Смартфоне(создал apk файл, и установил его).

Comment: При завершении работы приложения сделайте `DELETE FROM table_name;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто удаляете БД перед запуском. А при инициализации приложения делаем так:

```
db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
  + TableName
  + " (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR;");
```